# How does FF 13 lightning returns resolve differences of HP in costumes?

Tags: lightning-returns-final-fantasy-13

How does the game resolve different HPs of costumes?

I thought maybe it gave you the highest HP, or combined the HPs, but when I switch costumes in battle, it changes the shown HP, even though the bar remains the same. If each costume has it's own HP, how come the HP bar remains the same when you switch costumes?

If it is a different HP with each costume switch- If you are wearing a costume that has high enough HP for you to still be alive, but another custom does not give you enough HP to still be alive, what happens when you switch to this lower HP costume? You just die when you switch?

Answer (score 2):

I think the game keeps the percentage of remaining HP to determine how many HP you will have after the switch